# Reservation category of people born out of inter-caste marriages

Tags: civil-law, india, marriage, caste

## Background

In India there is reservation (for government employment and admissions etc) based on caste and income among other types.

For caste based reservation *mainly* following categories are there —

##### Reserved categories

- SC (scheduled caste)
- ST (scheduled tribe)
- OBC-NCL (Other Backward Class — Non creamy layer)
- General-EWS (Economically Weaker Section)

##### Non-reserved categories

- OBC-CL (Creamy layer)
- General-others (non EWS)

---

## My questions —

1. Is there default caste of child born out of inter-caste marriage? Or parents get to choose caste for child from among castes of theirs?
2. What will be the reservation category of a child when—

   - One parent belongs to non-reserved category and other belongs to reserved one.
   - Both parents belong to different reservation categories.

Comment: Good question. I don't know the answer and don't have adequate resources to find out.

Comment: @ohwilleke Can you please share this with somebody from India if you know someone who might answer this?

Comment: I wish I knew someone in India who did. We'll have to hope that one of our other readers has some insight into your question.

Comment: I have an inkling of an answer, but it will take some research. BRB

Answer (score 4):

**Is there default caste of child born out of inter-caste marriage?**

**Short answer**

- The child normally takes the father's caste, but it may be contested if it can be shown that the child is brought up by the mother.

**Long answer**

- The case law has been evolving in recent years, the latest findings by the Supreme Court of India can be found at [Rameshbhai Dabhai Naika vs State Of Gujarat & Ors on 18 January, 2012](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/197038546/)

> [T]he legal position that seems to emerge is that in an inter-caste marriage or a marriage between a tribal and a non-tribal **the determination of the caste of the offspring is essentially a question of fact** to be decided on the basis of the facts adduced in each case. The determination of caste of a person born of an inter-caste marriage or a marriage between a tribal and a non-tribal cannot be determined in complete disregard of attending facts of the case. In an inter- caste marriage or a marriage between a tribal and a non-tribal **there may be a presumption that the child has the caste of the father**. This presumption may be stronger in the case where in the inter-caste marriage or a marriage between a tribal and a non-tribal the husband belongs to a forward caste. **But by no means the presumption is conclusive or irrebuttable and it is open to the child of such marriage to lead evidence to show that he/she was brought up by the mother who belonged to the scheduled caste/scheduled tribe.**

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But sadly it only resolves ⅓rd of the issue.

Comment: @ShivCK The answers to your other, related, questions are the same - normally the father's caste unless the court rules otherwise

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess lack of a definitive law makes things complicated.